# Kendo UI MVC Grid Not Updating

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a Kendo UI grid in MVC with Entity Framework, and I am new to both of these. I have been using many of the tutorials from Kendo, and for this I have used Ajax Editior. This is what I have for the update in my controller, but the update does not fire.

```
 public ActionResult Opt_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, PQAViewModel   
 optData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {



            using (var pqaData = new PQAEntities())
            {
                var entity = new ProductQualityFileFull
                {
                    Jobber = optData.Jobber,
                    Dealer = optData.Dealer,
                    OptInd = optData.OptInd,
                    establish_date_time = optData.establish_date_time,
                    establish_id = optData.establish_id
                }; 
                pqaData.ProductQualityFileFulls.Attach(entity);
                pqaData.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; 
                pqaData.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(new[] { optData.OptInd }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
```

The two lines that it indactes the problem is at are here: Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 pqaData.ProductQualityFileFulls.Attach(entity);
 pqaData.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: If the Update "does not fire", then how do you know there's a problem with those two lines? And, if it DOES fire, what is the problem? What error message do you get?

Comment: In my network capturing it tells me to 'See EntityValidationErrors' and then highlights these as the source error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting EntityValidationErrors then put in a specific exception handler for EF e.g.

```
try{
using (var pqaData = new PQAEntities())
        {
            var entity = new ProductQualityFileFull
            {
                Jobber = optData.Jobber,
                Dealer = optData.Dealer,
                OptInd = optData.OptInd,
                establish_date_time = optData.establish_date_time,
                establish_id = optData.establish_id
            }; 
            pqaData.ProductQualityFileFulls.Attach(entity);
            pqaData.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; 
            pqaData.SaveChanges();
        }
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
 {
     //Check your errors here
}
```

It might be you're trying to put a null into a non-nullable field etc.

Comment: Yes that got rid of my error! Thank you so much! However it is not returning the update to my SQL database any idea on why this would be?